# Incorrect syntax near ':'. SQL image updating

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

Sorry for askin another one of these types of questions but I havent found a solution yet.
Here is the method where the error is coming from

```
 public int UpdatePhotos(string regno, string photoid,string photo)
    {
        string query = "UPDATE " + this.TableName + " SET PHOTOGRAPH = :PhotoParameter WHERE REG_NO = " + regno + " AND PHOTO_NO = '" + photoid + "'";

        SqlParameter photoParameter = new SqlParameter();
        photoParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image;
        photoParameter.ParameterName = "PhotoParameter";
        photoParameter.Value = Convert.FromBase64String(photo);
        SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand(query, this.Connection);
        cmnd.Parameters.Add(photoParameter);
        int featureCount = cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return featureCount;

    }
```

I have already tried changing the ":PhotoParameter" to be the byte[] coming straight from the file stream but I got the same error.
I cant find were the ":" is coming from to cause this error

Comment: What is the exception message/error code?

Comment: It doesn't give an error code just the "Incorrect syntax near ':'." message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

:PhotoParameter needs to be @PhotoParameter

Answer (score 0):

Just remove colon symbol in

```
SET PHOTOGRAPH = :PhotoParameter
```

and use

```
SET PHOTOGRAPH = @PhotoParameter
```

Comment: Like 21, that's only half the truth. Edit: now it's 42.

Comment: @cularis: You mean that line photoParameter.ParameterName = "PhotoParameter"; also should be updated?

Comment: My comment was before you ninja-edited the last 2 lines to your post.

Comment: :) yep, sometime happens when I post too quickly